# Optimize a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a view as below. The view takes a lot of time because both the tables have a lot of data. When I say a lot of data it means close to around 5,000,000 data for one table and we have two tables in all. On the top of it we are using UNION which takes more time. Please suggest a better way of tweaking this view so that the query gives a faster output.

```
CREATE view [dbo].[so_view]        
as        
    select * from (
        SELECT a.column_1,a.column_2,a.column_3,a.column_4,  
        coalesce(b.column_5,a.column_5) as [column_5]      
        FROM   table_1 a         
            left outer JOIN  table_2 b ON a.column_1 = b.column_1        
            AND a.column_2   = b.column_2        
            AND a. column_3 = b.column_3        
            AND a.column_4 = b.column_4        
        where a.column_4 = 1 and b.column_2   is null  
        union        
        SELECT a.column_1,a.column_2,a.column_3,a.column_4,  
        coalesce(b.column_5,a.column_5) as [column_5]      
        FROM   table_2 a         
            left outer JOIN table_1 b ON a.column_1 = b.column_1        
            AND a.column_2   = b.column_2        
            AND a. column_3 = b.column_3        
            AND a.column_4 = b.column_4        
        where a.column_4 = 1 
       )
```

Comment: First check you have appropriate Index applied on necessary columns or not.

Comment: You need to provide an execution plan when asking for performance advice.

Comment: "Please suggest a better way of tweaking this view so that the query gives a faster output." <- what's the actual query you're executing? This `CREATE VIEW` is going to execute in 1ms.

Comment: An easy initial win is to see if the results of your queries are logically non-overlapping (guaranteed not to produce duplicate rows). If so, you can use a `UNION ALL` rather than a `UNION`, skipping a final sort step of the result. With large result sets this makes a huge difference.

Comment: Please help us by providing the table definitions and some sample queries you're executing against the view with the  query plans. As it stands, we're mostly guessing.

Comment: Seems like a job for a full outer join rather than a union between two left-joined queries.

Comment: use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to share the execution plan

Comment: Explain the logic you want to implement.  The structure of the query looks unnecessarily awkward.

Comment: @mkRabbani Yes the indexes are aplied to the tables

Comment: @AakashM The actual query is  - select * from table_1 where column_1=<value> and column_2=<value>  --- This takes nearly 5-10 mins because of which I am getting an overall slowness effect

Comment: @Karanmehta that doesn't appear to involve the view mentioned in the question. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59319674/edit) your question to say exactly what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to implement a `full join`.  I *think* you want logic like this:

```
    SELECT COALESCE(a.column_1, b.column_1),
           COALESCE(a.column_2, b.column_2),
           COALESCE(a.column_3, b.column_3),
           COALESCE(a.column_4, b.column_4),
           COALESCE(b.column_5, a.column_5) as [column_5]      
    FROM table_1 a full   
         table_2 b
         ON a.column_1 = b.column_1 AND   
            a.column_2   = b.column_2 AND  
            a. column_3 = b.column_3 AND  
            a.column_4 = b.column_4        
    WHERE (a.mos_is_latest = 1 and b.analytics_id is null) OR
          (b.column_4 = 1);
```

Removing the `UNION` should significantly improve performance.